# angular 7 redirecting to another page

Tags: typescript, angular-routing, angular7

I have a login page and a dashboard component.My problem is when i login from the page the dashboard displays below the login page, it is not redirecting as a new page.How to achieve this in angular 7? Any help would be helpful'. Thanks!!

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Shopping-cart';
  user = []
  users = []
  public Candidate = []
  public showWhen:boolean = false;

  constructor(private _router: Router){}

  authenticateLogin(user){
    let authUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth'))
    console.log(user);
    if(user.mail === authUser[0] && user.password === authUser[1]){
      this.showWhen = true;
      console.log("Logged in Successfully");
      this._router.navigate(['dashboard']);
    } else {
      console.error("Invalid email and password");
    }
  }

}
```

This is my routing-module

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent} 
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: In `Routes` you have only one route - to dashboard - make second route to login

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski yeah your right!! now it redirects to the dashboard page. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I accepted your answer.My vote does not show as i have less than 15 reputations!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `Routes` you have only one route - to dashboard - make second route to login

Answer (score 1):

You should have another route to the login page. Without having that, you can't make any call to the login page.

In your part of code,
Try these chunks of code

> app.component.ts

```
authenticateLogin(user){
    let authUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth'))
    console.log(user);
    if(user.mail === authUser[0] && user.password === authUser[1]){
      this.showWhen = true;
      console.log("Logged in Successfully");
      this._router.navigate(['dashboard']);
    } else {
      this._router.navigate(['login']);
    }
  }
```

and you should have **another router path** in

> app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent} ,
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent(write your login component name)} 
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe for a login form, create your own component and add it to the route.

Comment: yes, i have done like that only and the problem was I din't add it to the route